# How modify int "auto-set" value in webservice request?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

Consider a soap 3 requests and a java class is mapped to they:

```
1.<Request>
     <intTag>
     </intTag>
   </Request>

2.<Request>
    <intTag/>
  </Request>

3.<Request>
  </Request>

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Request {
    @NotNull
    @XmlElement(required = true, name = "intTag")
    private Integer intTag;
}
```

So only for 3-rd request intTag=null, for 1-st and 2-nd intTag=0.
Why?
Is it possible to change the behaviour, and get null in all 3 requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use @XmlAdapter. See answer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894970/how-configure-jaxb-setters).

P.S. But I do not understand why there is no way like put true or false in @XmlElement ammotation.